# SQL connection commands doesn't change the data

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sqlconnection

How can I know whether the table in database is affected after these instructions? I try to show the query result in console but it doesn't show anything.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    DateTime date = new DateTime(2013, 3, 4);

    try 
    {
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ExchangeRatesByDate/TestApplication/Rates_DB.sdf");
        Console.WriteLine("Connection is created");

        connection.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Connection is opened");

        SqlCommand insertCommand = connection.CreateCommand();
        insertCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Rates_Table(ISO, Amount, Rate, Date) VALUES (USD, 1, 417.5, date)";
        insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM Rates_Table", connection);
        DataTable data = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(data);

        Console.WriteLine(adapter);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the console actually write? Error, nothing, ...? Also, your insertCommand is wrong - you have to use parameter substitution instead of just placing the `date`variable in a text string.

Answer (score 0):

the `ExecuteNonQuery()` returns an integer for the number of affected records.

```
int _affected = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

- [ExecuteNonQuery()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)

*follow-up question*

```
INSERT INTO Rates_Table(ISO, Amount, Rate, Date) VALUES (USD, 1, 417.5, date)
```

in the statement above, are values `USD` and `date` are real values because if so, it pretty sure it will thrown an exception. It should be wrap with single quotes like this:

```
INSERT INTO Rates_Table(ISO, Amount, Rate, Date) VALUES ('USD', 1, 417.5, '')
```

because they are string literals. But it's not the proper way to insert data with real values in the `INSERT` statement. The values should be parameterized to avoid `sql injection`.

```
string sqlStatement = "INSERT INTO Rates_Table(ISO, Amount, Rate, Date) VALUES (@iso, @Amount, @rate, @date)";
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    using(SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandText = sqlStatement;
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@iso", '-- value --');
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount", '-- value --');
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@rate", '-- value --');
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", '-- value --');

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            int _affected = comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch(SqlException e)
        {
            // do something with the exception
            // do not hide it
            // e.Message.ToString()
        }
    }
}
```

For proper coding

- use `using` statement for propr object disposal
- use `try-catch` block to properly handle objects

Comment: Ok. Thank you! But when I tried to read _affected, the console didn't show the result. Is my connection string written in correct form? My table's file name is Rates_Table.sql and it's in Rates_DB file

Comment: `Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;`

Answer (score 0):

`ExecuteNonQuery()` returns an integer showing number of affected rows.  [ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery.aspx)

> You can use the ExecuteNonQuery to perform catalog operations (for
>   example, querying the structure of a database or creating database
>   objects such as tables), or to change the data in a database without
>   using a DataSet by executing UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statements.
>   Although the ExecuteNonQuery returns no rows, any output parameters or
>   return values mapped to parameters are populated with data.
>
> For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the
>   number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a
>   table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number
>   of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number
>   of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of
>   statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return
>   value is also -1.

try like this

```
int updatedRows = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

if(updatedRows>0)
{
 //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think u are showing SqlDataAdapter  object show to datatable ,and also use parameter for the insert string like 'USD'